# Include only if minimum of 6 months activity

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I only include companies `b2b_id` with minimum activity of 1 invoice per month for 6 months.

```
SELECT
  b2b_id,
  uid,
  issue_date),
  due_date,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM t_invoice
GROUP BY b2b_id, last_day(issue_date)
HAVING cnt >= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leverage the having clause with one more condition. Note the aggregate use does not have to exist in the select clause.

```
SELECT
      b2b_id
    , uid
    , issue_date
    , due_date
    , COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM t_invoice
GROUP BY
      b2b_id
    , last_day(issue_date)
HAVING cnt >= 1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT (case when issue_date >= (current_date - interval 6 month) then month(issue_date) end)) = 6
```

Not sure which date column is used, I chose issue_date

- If the issue_date  is >= today minus 6 months then return that month number
- count the distinct month numbers
- if 6, then at least one isse_date per month, in the last 6 months